# Syntax error on token "return", invalid Type?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm trying to complete this exercise from codingbat.com in Java. I get this error "Syntax error on token "return", invalid Type" on this little bit of code and I'm having trouble figuring out why. I'm trying to return the number of times the word "hi" appears in a given String. Thanks!

```
public int countHi(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++){
        if(str.substring(i, i + 2).equals("hi"));
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public int countHi(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++){
        if(str.substring(i, i + 2).equals("hi")); // 1
            count++;
        } // 2
    }
    return count;
}
```

The issue is that you have an `;` rather than a `{` after your `if` condition (1), which essentially means the `if` body is empty. The `}` after the `count++` line (2) is, in turn, treated as the end of the `for` loop (rather than the `if` as it should be), and the `}` that should end the `for` loop instead ends the method.

That leaves your `return count;` and final `}` hanging in the middle of a class definition where it's not valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`return count;` is outside the method and you have a `;` after your `if` that shouldn't be there, after good indentation and removing this `;`, you'll get:

```
public int countHi(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if(str.substring(i, i + 2).equals("hi")) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    //Return should be here
}   //Method countHI ends here
    return count;  //??
}
```

Now you see why it's **very important** to put braces even if the body contains only one line?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the word "redundant" in your answer is misleading. Redundancy means repetitious or unneeded, but the `;` is actually harmful -- it completely changes the meaning of the `if` statement. If you had `...).equals("hi")); {` then the `if` statement would conditionally execute an empty block, and `count++` would be in an "anonymous" block that's _always_ executed.

Comment: @yshavit English is my third language :) Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an opening bracket after your `if()` condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is a semicolon after your conditional in your `if` statement.

```
 if(str.substring(i, i + 2).equals("hi"));
```

Comment: And your answer is misleading.